# \raggedyleft in memoir?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir

In memoir instead of `\raggedright`, you can use `\raggedyright[<space>]` which is much more beautiful in narrow columns. However what I also need is `\raggedyleft` which does not exist and I don't know why. This is the implementation of `\raggedyright` in `memoir`:

```
\newdimen\ragrparindent
  \setlength{\ragrparindent}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\raggedyright}[1][2em]{%
  \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip \z@ \@plus #1\relax
%%%  \rightskip\@rightskip
  \memRTLrightskip\@rightskip
%%%  \leftskip\z@skip
  \memRTLleftskip\z@skip
  \parindent\ragrparindent}
```

As someone who does not know `TeX` macro very much, I could not figure out how it works exactly. I appreciate if someone here can explain me this code and tell me what to do to have `\raggedyleft`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

lockstep gave the definition; let's look at what the original code means.

```
\newdimen\ragrparindent
```

This sets up a new parameter.

```
  \setlength{\ragrparindent}{\parindent}
```

This sets the value; I'd prefer

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \setlength{\ragrparindent}{\parindent}
}
```

but the developers of `memoir` chose differently.

```
\newcommand{\raggedyright}[1][2em]{%
```

This starts the definition of `\raggedyright` which has an optional argument, with default value 2em

```
  \let\\\@centercr
```

This says that `\\` must be `\@centercr`, a wrapper command of the LaTeX kernel used in `\raggedright`, `\centering` and `\raggedleft` for properly ending lines.

```
  \@rightskip \z@ \@plus #1\relax
%%%  \rightskip\@rightskip
  \memRTLrightskip\@rightskip
```

The internal parameter `\@rightskip` is set to a flexible glue with natural width 0pt and stretchability equal to the value given as optional argument. The commented line would set `\rightskip` to equal `\@rightskip`; `\rightskip` is an amount of glue that TeX always adds to the right of the lines (and is usually zero. For compatibility with the `bidi` package the parameter `\memRTLrightskip` is set instead (so it will be `\rightskip` in LTR writing, `\leftskip` in RTL writing).

```
%%%  \leftskip\z@skip
  \memRTLleftskip\z@skip
```

The leftskip is set to zero.

```
  \parindent\ragrparindent}
```

This ends the definition, by setting the `\parindent` (we might be in a situation where the parindent has been changed or cleared).

So, changing what's needed, the definition of `\raggedyleft` would be

```
\newcommand{\raggedyleft}[1][2em]{%
  \let\\\@centercr
  \leftskip \z@ \@plus #1\relax
  \memRTLleftskip\leftskip
  \memRTLrightskip\z@skip
  \parindent=\z@
  \parfillskip=\z@skip}
```

While in a ragged right setting a non zero parindent can be desirable (indeed, it *is*), in a ragged left setting it's definitely not needed. And there's another adjustment to do: also the final line should be flush right, so also `\parfillskip` must be set to zero.

There is an asymmetry between left and right, because `\rightskip` is used also in the `trivlist` environment and so the kernel needs a "duplicate register" for maintaining a stable value. This isn't the case for `\leftskip`, so there is *no* `\@leftskip`.

---

A word about `\z@`, `\z@skip` and `\@plus`. The first is a dimension register that's permanently set to 0pt and, by the rules of TeX, can be used in all situations TeX needs a dimension or an integer number (to denote 0pt or 0 respectively). Next, `\z@skip` is a skip register permanently set to `0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt` and can be used to set to zero any skip parameter (*rubber length* in LaTeXspeak).

`\@plus` stands for the keyword `plus`, like `\@minus` for `minus`, so

```
\z@skip\z@ \@plus \z@ \@minus \z@
```

is the same as saying

```
\z@skip=0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt
```

but in a definition the former uses six tokens, while the latter uses 24. When the LaTeX kernel was written, token memory considerations were very important, so it has become customary to still use the "abbreviated forms" that, however, have another advantage: they lift some burden in taking into account spaces that should be present but are eventually ignored.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. You might want to add a bit about `\parfillskip\z@skip` (which I copied from `\raggedleft`).

Comment: Also note that the LaTeX2e core doesn't feature `\@leftskip`, so I think it's correct to simply say `\memRTLleftskip\z@ \@plus #1\relax`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I should say I am familiar with the syntax and can follow it quite well. I have problems with things like `\z@`, `\@plus`. How should one know to use these instead of their equivalent non `@` version? Where can I find these kinds of information? In `LaTeX2e` source?

Comment: @rowman Indeed. Use `texdoc source2e` to access the source documentation.

Answer (score 6):

One basically needs to look up the differences between `\raggedright` (LaTeX2e core) and `\raggedyright` (`memoir`) and then tinker with the definition of `\raggedleft` {LaTeX2e core) to create `\raggedyleft`. Note that I didn't implement a `\raglparindent` length.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raggedyleft}[1][2em]{%
  \let\\\@centercr
  \memRTLleftskip\z@ \@plus #1\relax
  \memRTLrightskip\z@skip
  \parindent\z@
  \parfillskip\z@skip
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\raggedleft

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

\raggedyleft

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

\raggedyleft[1fil]% same effect as \raggedleft

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]