# What's the difference between @minus and minus?

Tags: spacing

When I look at different uses of glue in spacing, I see both `\@minus` and `minus`.

What's the difference between \@minus and minus?

Comment: latex format define `\def\@minus{minus}`

Comment: Nothing really. In the old days `\@minus` just saved a few things in Texs memory (or something like that, there is a word for what was saved, but I've forgotten it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see some information in my answer to [\raggedyleft in memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84465/raggedyleft-in-memoir)

The expansions of `\@minus` and `\@plus` are, respectively, `minus` and `plus`. But `\@minus` counts as one token in the replacement text of a macro, whereas `minus` counts as five.

Now, `\@plus` appears 16 times in `latex.ltx` (one is the definition), 15 times in `article.cls` and 36 times in `size10.clo`, which makes for a saving of (15+15+36)*(4–1) = 198 tokens on every standard document in the `article` class. This might appear ridiculous nowadays, but, when LaTeX2e was released, memory was really scarce and even such savings were worthwhile. There are several other token saving tricks such as `\z@`, `\p@`, `\hb@xt@` and so on, which (on some TeX distributions) made the difference between being able to run LaTeX or not.